# Manually insert mesh into CGAL with points and cells

Tags: c++, cgal

I have a triangular mesh written down on a piece of paper with a bunch of nodes and their connectivity. I'd like to put in this mesh into CGAL, to, e.g., play around with Lloyd smoothing, computing the Voronoi diagram etc.

I'm looking at [Mesh_2/mesh_optimization.cpp](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_2/Mesh_2_2mesh_optimization_8cpp-example.html)
 which apparently allows the inserting of points

```
CDT cdt;
Vertex_handle va = cdt.insert(Point(-2,0));
Vertex_handle vb = cdt.insert(Point(0,-2));
Vertex_handle vc = cdt.insert(Point(2,0));
Vertex_handle vd = cdt.insert(Point(0,1));
```

but not cells (triangles).

Any hint on where to start?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar situation. Caveat: I didn't need to use the those specific algorithms, so I'm not sure how this solution works with those.

You can use the `CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2` ([wiki](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/TDS_2/classCGAL_1_1Triangulation__data__structure__2.html)) to manually specify faces, neighbours, and vertices.

```
#include <CGAL/Triangulation_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Projection_traits_xy_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Triangulation_ds_face_base_2.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;  
    typedef K::Point_3 Point_3;
    typedef CGAL::Projection_traits_xy_3<K> Gt; //allows for using 2D algorithms on the 3D points (good for terrain)
    typedef CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_2<Gt> Vb; 
    typedef CGAL::Constrained_triangulation_face_base_2<Gt> Fb; 
    typedef CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<Vb, Fb> triangulation;

    triangulation tri;
    //read in x,y,z from a file here
    //create a new vertex and insert into a 2D triangulation

    //vertex 0
    int x,y,z;
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    z=0;
    Point_3 pt0( x,y,z); 
    auto Vh0 = tri.create_vertex(); // type of Vh0 is triangulation::Vertex_handle
    Vh0->set_point(pt0);

    //vertex 1
    x = 1;
    y = 0;
    z=0;
    Point_3 pt1( x,y,z);
    auto Vh1 = tri.create_vertex();
    Vh1->set_point(pt1);

    //vertex 2
    x = 0.5;
    y = 0.5;
    z=0;
    Point_3 pt2( x,y,z);
    auto Vh2= tri.create_vertex();
    Vh2->set_point(pt2);

    auto face = tri.create_face(Vh0,Vh1,Vh1); // type of face is triangulation::Face_handle
    Vh0->set_face(face);
    Vh1->set_face(face);
    Vh2->set_face(face);

    std::cout << "#veterx=" << tri.number_of_vertices() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "#faces=" << tri.faces().size() << std::endl;

}
```

and if you have more than 1 face, you can set face neighbours

```
    face->set_neighbors(face0,face1,face2);
```

CMakeLists.txt to build the example:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.12)
project (tri)
find_package(CGAL REQUIRED)
include(${CGAL_USE_FILE})



include_directories(
        ${CGAL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
        ${CGAL_3RD_PARTY_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(main
                main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(main ${CGAL_3RD_PARTY_LIBRARIES})
```